# GIT: How to revert local files to state before first fetch

Tags: git, laravel

guess I really got myself some trouble after a too long day.
I just started working on a new DevEnv and copied the files from a GitRepo into the dev www folder.
After hours of work I wanted to push this to a branch of the repo.

What I did was:

- git init
- git remote add origin ...
- git fetch --all
- git add .
- git commit ...
- git checkout RC
- git push origin RC

**Obviously that was very wrong and stupid** since it crashed all my local files and overwrode it with the Remote-Version (as is normal..).

So I guess my question is: Is there any way to revert all the changes to the state they were before messing up with git :/.

Kind regards and thanks for any help...

Comment: Correct Order of commands:
What I did was:

 - git init
 - git remote add origin ...
 - git fetch --all
 - git add .
 - git commit ... 
 - git checkout RC
 - git push origin RC

Comment: From that workflow, I don't see a _real_ problem. When you committed, you hadn't yet checked out any given branch from the remote so it created a new branch called _master_ and committed there with the content of the files as you had them... no relation to any other branch. Then you checked out another branch which I guess exists on the remote and so git created the branch on your local tracking the remote one. Then you pushed that same branch with no changes, so push shouldn't have done anything....

Comment: ... Did I miss anything? What where you expecting to see? I mean, I know this is not what you wanted. I only want to know what you _really_ want to do.

Comment: Agreed with @eftshift0, couldn't you run `git checkout master` and be back to your local files?

Comment: True, the push did not do anything. I want to go back and have the version of my files as they were before I did anything with git - is that possible? Sorry, I am really not that good within git (as you can see), I am just coding for fun :(:
Doing checkout master woul bring me to the remote "master" branch, would it?

Comment: You can run `git branch -v -a` to verify to yourself/visualize what @eftshift0 just described

Comment: If what you want to do is get the files the way they were, as @HFBrowsing said, `git checkout master` should do.

Comment: git branch -v -a bring up the following: $ git branch -v -a
* RC     bfaf770 Update GroupController.php
  master 1213aba initial

Comment: Yup - so how to read it is `<name_of_branch> <short_hash> <commit_msg>` . Which shows you have a local `master` and a remote named `RC`. Feel free to freely checkout back and forth between `master` and `RC` - you'll see your files in the directory change back and forth. The heart of the magic of git - nothing is lost here :)

Comment: Jesus! Git checkout master worked! Thanks to all of you, just saved my free day :) ! God bless you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THANKS TO @HFBrowning and @eftshift0**

The solution in this case was simply to git checkout master.

Thanks SO-Community! :)